# Get Position in SVG relative to mouse click position in order to draw over SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I need some help on a problem i am having. I have a SVG of body map. I have rendered the SVG in browser. I can access its elements via javascript and i can add line/path or other elements to the svg file.

What i am having problem is getting the exact location relative to SVG when mouse moved over the rednered SVG.

What i need to get is to be able to draw where ever mouse moves on the SVG

What I have tried so far is following

```
element.getBBox()
```

Output `{x: 4129, y: 2864, width: 885.68505859375, height: 1271.2607421875}`

but it returns the starting co-ordinates of box in which element resides rather then the exact position where i clicked.

I tried less reliable solution as well but i am not sure how i should translate its output to the co-ordinates of SVG

```
element.getBoundingClientRect()
```

output `{x: 141.24688720703125, y: 97.97314453125, width: 30.297958374023438, height: 43.4879150390625, top: 97.97314453125, …}`

I have also tried using a function i found here in some questions

```
function getElementCoords(element, coords) {
    var ctm = element.getCTM(),
        x = ctm.e + coords.x * ctm.a + coords.y * ctm.c,
        y = ctm.f + coords.x * ctm.b + coords.y * ctm.d;
    return { x: x, y: y };
}
```

now this function keeps other matters like zoom in equation too but what it returns me the co-ordinates which are of no use to me.

e.g `<line xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x1="4129" y1="2864" x2="4139" y2="2874" style="stroke: red; stroke-width: 40px;"/>`

I want to draw where i move the mouse over SVG. All i need to know what `x1, y1, x2, y2` are when i am moving a mouse over the SVG file.

I can get the mouse position and i can get the position of box in SVG but can not get exact location.

I have searched online every where but could not find anything relating to what i want to achieve. Any help or pointer to some solution is appreciated.

Comment: [tag:d3.js] contains this functionality: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#mouse, relevant source code: https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/src/point.js

Comment: Thanks but this does not work. In my case I already have the SVG and I have to draw over that. Now the SVG x, y are in like as you seen in above question. Where as when you get client X, Y they are relative to the screen you are rendering the SVG. What I need is some way to convert the client end points to the SVG points.